# How to map the start vertex to all the vertices it is reachable to?

Tags: gremlin, gremlin-server, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi, gremlinpython

I am trying to come up with a gremlin query that maps the start node to all the nodes  it is reachable to.

So for example, if the graph is something like this:

```
node1--link-->node2--link-->node3--link-->node4
```

the response I am expecting from query is:

```
[start=node1, relates=[node2, node3, node4]]
```

So here, if node3 is reachable to lets say node5 and node6, they also should be included in the result.

I have written the query: https://gremlify.com/hatp1roeii
But the response is not what I expected.

Answer (score 0):

Using the test data (reformatted for readability) from the Gremlify example:

```java
g.addV('node').as('1').property(single, 'recordId', 'node9').property(single, 'data', 22).
  addV('node').as('2').property(single, 'recordId', 'node10').property(single, 'data', 16).
  addV('root').as('3').property(single, 'recordId', 'node1').property(single, 'data', 9).
  addV('node').as('4').property(single, 'recordId', 'node2').property(single, 'data', 5).
  addV('node').as('5').property(single, 'recordId', 'node4').property(single, 'data', 2).
  addV('node').as('6').property(single, 'recordId', 'node3').property(single, 'data', 11).
  addV('node').as('7').property(single, 'recordId', 'node7').property(single, 'data', 15).
  addV('node').as('8').property(single, 'recordId', 'node6').property(single, 'data', 10).
  addV('node').as('9').property(single, 'recordId', 'node8').property(single, 'data', 1).
  addV('node').as('10').property(single, 'recordId', 'node5').property(single, 'data', 8).
  addE('left').from('1').to('2').
  addE('left').from('3').to('4').
  addE('right').from('3').to('6').
  addE('left').from('4').to('5').
  addE('right').from('4').to('10').
  addE('left').from('5').to('9').
  addE('left').from('6').to('8').
  addE('right').from('6').to('7').
  addE('right').from('7').to('1')
```

All of the paths from 'node1' can be discovered using

```java
gremlin> g.V().has('recordId','node1').
......1>       repeat(out()).
......2>       until(__.not(out())).
......3>       path().by('recordId')
 
==>[node1,node2,node5]
==>[node1,node3,node6]
==>[node1,node2,node4,node8]
==>[node1,node3,node7,node9,node10]
```

We can `dedup` that result to get the unique list of nodes visited

```java
gremlin> g.V().has('recordId','node1').
......1>       repeat(out()).
......2>       until(__.not(out())).
......3>       path().by('recordId').
......4>       unfold().
......5>       dedup().
......6>       fold()  

==>[node1,node2,node5,node3,node6,node4,node8,node7,node9,node10]
```

While not the nicely formatted answer yet, this is essentially one way of solving the problem.  We can modify the query above to get the formatted result described in the question:

```java
gremlin> g.V().has('recordId','node1').
......1>       repeat(out()).
......2>       until(__.not(out())).
......3>       path().by('recordId').
......4>       unfold().
......5>       dedup().
......6>       fold().
......7>       project('start','relates_to').
......8>         by(limit(local,1)).
......9>         by(skip(local,1))   

==>[start:node1,relates_to:[node2,node5,node3,node6,node4,node8,node7,node9,node10]]
```

Here is the same query, but starting at 'node7'

```java
gremlin> g.V().has('recordId','node7').
......1>       repeat(out()).
......2>       until(__.not(out())).
......3>       path().by('recordId').
......4>       unfold().
......5>       dedup().
......6>       fold().
......7>       project('start','relates_to').
......8>         by(limit(local,1)).
......9>         by(skip(local,1)) 

==>[start:node7,relates_to:[node9,node10]]
```

Lastly, here's a version that does not use the `path` step, but instead uses `store` to aggregate the nodes visited.

```java
gremlin> g.V().has('recordId','node1').store('start').
......1>       repeat(out().store('seen')).
......2>       until(__.not(out())).
......3>       cap('seen').dedup(local).unfold().values('recordId').fold().
......4>       project('start','relates_to').
......5>         by(cap('start').unfold().values('recordId')).
......6>         by() 

==>[start:node1,relates_to:[node2,node3,node4,node5,node6,node7,node8,node9,node10]]
```

and from 'node7'

```java
gremlin> g.V().has('recordId','node7').store('start').
......1>       repeat(out().store('seen')).
......2>       until(__.not(out())).
......3>       cap('seen').dedup(local).unfold().values('recordId').fold().
......4>       project('start','relates_to').
......5>         by(cap('start').unfold().values('recordId')).
......6>         by()  

==>[start:node7,relates_to:[node9,node10]]
```